# How to start `gnome-keyring-daemon` outside of Unity?

Tags: login, gnome-keyring, i3-wm

I'm running Ubuntu with i3WM instead of Unity (while Unity is still available as a choice on the login screen).

`gnome-keyring-daemon` works fine with Unity which starts it automatically. I just don't see how to start it with i3WM so that all module works.

I tried this from `.profile`:

```
if [ -n "$GNOME_KEYRING_PID" ]; then
   export $(gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh,gpg)
fi
```

GPG and SSH agents at least works, but Secrets does not work.

I tried this from `.config/i3/config`:

```
exec --no-startup-id gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh,gpg
```

Secrets works, but GPG and SSH agents does not work.

How do I start `gnome-keyring-daemon` so that **all components** works, and not just either GPG and SSH or Secrets?

Comment: The defaults are supposed to be inclusive I think - what happens if you don't add the `--components` option at all?

Comment: @steeldriver, this is something I already tried earlier, and it was the same.

Comment: The [Archlinux gnome-keyring](http://Archlinux%20gnome-keyring) wiki page provides a comprehensive list of techniques to start the keyring from outside of Unity.
According to the page, the keyring should start automatically at login, thanks to lightdm (if that's the login manager you are using). Like you, I'm using i3wm and encounter the same issue. Starting the keyring via i3 config gives me other issues.
I suspect we need to find a way to parse the following files to achieve the maximum compatibility:
/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-*

Answer (score 2):

In order for `gnome-keyring-daemon` (and other gnome bits) to work properly they needs to live within a dbus session shared by other portions of the desktop environment. The best way to do this is probably to use one of the gnome+i3 repositories floating around in order to launch i3 via a gnome-session. I have a work-in-progress home directory only solution (no system file edits) at https://github.com/dragon788/i3-gnome-homedir drawing on previous work by TheMarek, lvillani and MeanEYE (also on Github).

I don't explicitly start the gnome-keyring stuff in mine (using gpg-agent and/or keychain instead), but you could potentially do it via .desktop files in `~/.config/autostart` or adding the respective .desktop names minus the extension to `~/.config/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-plus-i3.session` (in my repo above) to trigger during the session startup. The other repos with gnome+i3 may give you more examples to draw from.